# Assign Different port number for 1 website alone on Linux Server with multisite on single IP

Tags: tomcat, linux

I have Linux VPS. 
**Configuration**
 Linux CentOS with cPanel Default port :80

**Servers running** 
Apache for PHP (default in cPanel) Tomcat 5.5.33

I have a only 1 IP alloted for it. Have multiple domains hosted on it.

**MY PROBLEM:** 
All domains are running on port :80 but i need only 1 of my domain to run in port :8080

I'm able to access my domain as www.example.com:8080 but i need to access it as www.example.com (8080 should deliver instead of default 80)

**My references**
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html 
http://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/centos-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found solution from the hints given in previous posts

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^admin(.*)$ http://example.com/tryAdmin$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/try/$1 [R,L]
```

**/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/tryord/example.com/extra.conf**

```
ProxyPass         /try  http://example.com:8080/try
ProxyPassReverse  /try  http://example.com:8080/try
ProxyPass         /tryAdmin  http://example.com:8080/tryAdmin
ProxyPassReverse  /tryAdmin  http://example.com:8080/tryAdmin
```

**References**
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html#Apache_2.0_Proxy_Support

> Apache - /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf Tomcat -
>   /usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/conf/server.xml

Include

```
/usr/local/apache/modules/mod_proxy.so
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to transparently access the tomcat content on www.example.com:8080 by simply accessing www.example.com - there's a few methods to do this:

1) if you have mod-rewrite enabled, try something like this in your vhost definition or in a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8080%{REQUEST_URI}
```

2) if you wanna back-proxy it (needs mod_proxy_http enabled)
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/proxy.html

Comment: The port forwarding is working. But i need to mask the 8080 port from browser view. Also If i need to forward the above to some subfolder as default, how can i make it? RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8080/sub%{REQUEST_URI} is causing problem while i try to access example.com/admin in browser (it redirects to example.com/sub/admin 404error )

Comment: @mohan.hab, if you want to "mask the 8080 port" (i.e. use port 80), you need to use one of the reverse proxy methods, not `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0):

You get two categories of options: redirection or reverse proxy (which you can do within a specific `VirtualHost` configuration, if you need this to be for only one host name).

The redirection can be done using `mod_rewrite` (as @O G says).

Since the server running on port 8080 is effectively a different server from Apache HTTPD on port 80, `mod_rewrite` can't rewrite URLs internally (so it only works in redirection mode). Instead, you can use a reverse proxy method:

- `mod_jk2` (from @O G's link) is [considered "historical"](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi).
- [`mod_jk`](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/) is rather stable, but it relies on the AJP protocol, so you wouldn't need to enable it on your Tomcat configuration (probably not on port 8080).
- [`mod_proxy_ajp`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html) is also rather stable and often comes by default with Apache HTTPD (unlike `mod_jk`), at least with version 2.2. It also uses the AJP protocol, so you would need to configure Apache Tomcat accordingly too.
- Otherwise, you could use an HTTP reverse proxy, with [`mod_proxy_http`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) (without the need for AJP).